# Creating 5.0 atmospheres & Panning

Tags: panning, ambience, atmosphere

Hey there,

Have been playing round with some stereo atmospheres i recorded, trying to make them into 5.0s I can bounce and use in the future as pre made surround  backgrounds. I would normally just pan in Pro Tools but figuring it would be nice phase wise to make them 5.0 through a plugin. (And yes ideally record them 5.0 in first place but I sadly don't have a surround mic). Ive tried 2 versions using Waves UM226, and Waves S360 imager. I've folded them back through Surround Code plug to stereo to check phase. Some presets sound a little phasey but Ive found a nice one for each plugin that works. Seems like a nice spread in 5.0.

Anyone had experience of this - or recommendations - a good idea, or am I just wasting my time??

Also, when tracklaying do people tend to create 5.0 atmospheres by simply panning a stereo in Pro tools, or by using a different section of the atmos for the rears,  or only use 5.0 recorded atmospheres or anything else? And do people diverge a stereo atmos or only use discrete panning for backgrounds. I guess I personally do a combination of all, depending on the situation and particular track - but would be interested to hear how other people work.

Thanks
A

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that, unless you're doing fast turnaround episodic TV stuff, it's best not to prefabricate 5.0 backgrounds. That way you can have more control in the mix.

I asked a similar question a while back, and got some awesome answers:

[Mixing backgrounds/atmos for 5.1](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/mixing-backgrounds-atmos-for-5-1)